# Is there a way to drop views or tables within Apache Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I like the ability to easily CTA or CVA within superset.  But sometimes I want to drop a view or table, and it doesn't seem like the SQL Lab allows for this.  Anybody know a workaround?

(using Amazon Redshift btw)

Answer (score 2):

In the database properties form, there's a property called "Allow DML" that needs to be switched on in order to allow users to run non-SELECT statements like DROP/UPDATE/DELETE/.

[image: Allow DML]

Note that if you do want to enable only some of the users to do this, it's common two create two database connection entries (one with DML and one without), label them appropriately (ie "Redshift EAST - with DML") and associate them with different roles.